# How to deal with the error: /Users/simo/.gradle/daemon/6.5/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I downloaded an Android app project from Github, and when I opened it with Android Studio, the following error occurs:
Event Log:

```
Gradle sync failed: /Users/simo/.gradle/daemon/6.5/app/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml (No such file or directory)
```

Can someone explain to me the nature of the problem and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My wild guess would be, that there is no file "styles.xml" in this folder.
Maybe u can post the github repo?

Comment: Maybe a quick fix can be, just to create an empty styles file in this location.

Comment: Here's the github repo:https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/MemeTastic

Comment: Well it seems like they try to get infos of your .gradle folder where they are looking for app infos.

In the gradle file I commented line 28 out: 

      
        //buildConfigField("String[]", "APPLICATION_LANGUAGES", '{' + getUsedAndroidLanguages().collect {"\"${it}\""}.join(",")  + '}')

this is not needed. Afterwards the app builds for me.

Comment: I created the repo “/Users/simo/.gradle/daemon/6.5/app/src/main” and then paste in it a copy of the “res” file from my dowloaded project. And it worked (for now). Thanks mate.